# Instance Variable vs getter/setter

Tags: c#

Can you help to describe the trade off between storing a calculated field such as the area of a rectangle in an instance variable and calculating it each time the getter for the area is called?

Comment: probably negligible unless the calculation is complex (which the area of a rectangle definitely isn't), or you are fetching it thousands of times in quick succession.

Comment: Calculating the result once is obviously faster than calculating it on-the-fly all the time.

Comment: Storing instance variable can cause duplicated data... and thus data inconsistency.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. Are you trying to optimize for something in particular? Speed? Memory? Please edit your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me there are two options:

1. Calculate the value in the `get` method each time the property is accessed.
2. Store the value in a private backing field and update it each time it needs to change (i.e. each time the width or height changes).

So the answer depends on which happens more frequently: accessing the calculated value, or changing the calculated value (i.e. changing the size of the rectangle).

**If the size of the rectangle changes more often than the `Area` is accessed**, then it would be more efficient to only calculate the value when it's needed (to avoid a lot of "thrown-away" calculations each time the size changes):

```
class Rectangle
{
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Area => Width * Height;    // Calculate the value when accessed
}
```

**If the `Area` is accessed more often than the size changes**, then it would be more efficient to store the calculated value (to avoid a lot of redundant calculations that result in the same value each time because the size hasn't changed):

```
class Rectangle
{
    public int Width
    {
        get { return width; }
        set
        {
            if (width == value) return;
            width = value;
            Area = width * height;        // Store the new calculated value
        }
    }

    public int Height
    {
        get { return height; }
        set
        {
            if (height == value) return;
            height = value;
            Area = width * height;        // Store the new calculated value
        }
    }

    public int Area { get; private set; }

    private int width;
    private int height;
}
```

---

**However, efficiency isn't everything**

In this particular example, the performance between either of these options will be negligible, so I would simply go with the first option since it's much less code, easier to read, and easier to maintain.